# Extracting from a list of list of data.frames in R?

Tags: r, list, function, loops, dataframe

I have a list of list of data.frames called `G`.

In BASE R, I was wondering how I could *separately* extract elements `dint` and `SD` in `AA` and `BB` whose 
data.frame colnames ***contains*** `short` `del1` and `del2` (see my ***desired output*** below)?

```
G <- list(AA = list(short = data.frame(dint = 5:7, SD = 0:2), short..2 = NULL, del1 = data.frame(dint = 1:3, SD = 2:4), 
               del1..2 = NULL, del2 = NULL), 

          BB = list(short = data.frame(dint = 1:4, SD = 2:5), short..2 = NULL, del1 = 
                 data.frame(dint = 5:6, SD = 3:4), del1..2 = NULL, del2 = data.frame(dint = 6, SD = 1)) )
```

**My desired output is:**

```
# dints:
dints = list(
short = list(AA = c(short = 5:7), BB = c(short = 1:4)),
 del1 = list(AA = c(del1 = 1:3), BB = c(del1 = 5:6)),
 del2 = list(AA = c(del2 = NULL), BB = c(del2 = 6)))


# SDs:
SDs = list(
short = list(AA = c(short = 0:2), BB = c(short = 2:5)),
 del1 = list(AA = c(del1 = 2:4), BB = c(del1 = 3:4)),
 del2 = list(AA = c(del2 = NULL), BB = c(del2 = 1)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this function should extract what you need.

```
foo <- function(G, val="dint", cols = c("short", "del1", "del2")) {
  named <- function(x, n) {if (is.null(x)) x else setNames(list(x), n)}  
  Map(function(col) Map(function(n) named(G[[n]][[col]][[val]], col), names(G)), cols)
}

dints <- foo(G, "dint")
SDs <- foo(G, "SD")
```

I used lists rather than named vectors for the inner most values. Not sure what the logic was in dropping the `..2` values so I just made a parameter to specify which sub values you wanted to extract.

Comment: You can choose what you want to capture with the `cols =` parameter. I just hard coded it with the values you used in your desired output.

Comment: I don't see why that would be impossible. Free free to change the code to do what you like. This version gives the output you requested in your original question.