# Follow-up: Extracting from a list of list of data.frames in R?

Tags: r, list, function, loops, dataframe

A follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58420181/extracting-from-a-list-of-list-of-data-frames-in-r): I have a list of list of data.frames called `G`.

In BASE R, I was wondering how I could *separately* extract elements `dint` and `SD` in `AA` and `BB` whose 
data.frame colnames has the **base name** of `short` `del1` and `del2` (see my ***desired output*** below)?

***Note:*** The solution provided [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58420684/7223434) ignores suffixed names like `short..3` etc.

```
G <- list(AA = list(short..3 = data.frame(dint = 5:7, SD = 0:2), short..2 = NULL, del1 = data.frame(dint = 1:3, SD = 2:4), 
               del1..2 = NULL, del2 = NULL), 

          BB = list(short = data.frame(dint = 1:4, SD = 2:5), short..2 = NULL, del1..4 = 
                 data.frame(dint = 5:6, SD = 3:4), del1..2 = NULL, del2 = data.frame(dint = 6, SD = 1)) )
```

**My desired output is (I want inner names e.g., "short" not be auto-suffixed):**

```
# dints:
dints = list(
short = list(AA = c(short = 5:7), BB = c(short = 1:4)),
 del1 = list(AA = c(del1 = 1:3), BB = c(del1 = 5:6)),
 del2 = list(AA = c(del2 = NULL), BB = c(del2 = 6)))


# SDs:
SDs = list(
short = list(AA = c(short = 0:2), BB = c(short = 2:5)),
 del1 = list(AA = c(del1 = 2:4), BB = c(del1 = 3:4)),
 del2 = list(AA = c(del2 = NULL), BB = c(del2 = 1)))
```

Comment: What happens when you have values for both `short...3` and `short..2`?

Comment: Really? Then no values for `short` are returned? You might want to update your example to make that clear.